# MVC 5 routing with parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to create an edit action method which takes id as the parameter to get the employee from the database and allow the user to edit the details.Here is my code for edit action.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            EmployeeData eData = new EmployeeData();
            Employee employee = eData.Employees.Single(x => x.ID == id);
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
```

This my router-config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

I tried using attribute routing and still not able to get the desired result.And I am getting this error message

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'WebApplication1.Controllers.EmployeeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: It works perfectly if a supply the ID in Url explicitly though."Employee/Edit/100" works perfectly, but I want url to take the id parameter implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to edit the Html helper Actionlink for Edit in the Index page from

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */}) |

to

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.ID }) |

so now the URL takes the id value directly from the index page of the Employee view.